# Unexpected results inside a loop with selects

Tags: abap, opensql

I select data from transparent tables and cluster tables and put the result into an internal table. As cluster tables can't be joined, I used two `select single` for retrieving data from the cluster tables.

The problem is that, in the loop, each output line is assigned the same information of the first line in the internal table (`D` at each line). Maybe it's because the field of the where condition retrieves 3 lines with the same value from the `BELNR` column.

First, here is the code:

```
FORM select_data1 CHANGING lt_data LIKE gt_map1.   
  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_main> TYPE zimposto_consumo.

  SELECT a~belnr d~spart a~bldat a~waers c~wrbtr a~hwaer c~dmbtr  
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_data
          FROM ( ( bkpf AS a
      INNER JOIN bsis AS c ON c~belnr = a~belnr )
      INNER JOIN vbrk AS d ON d~xblnr = c~belnr )
      WHERE a~belnr IN belnr.


  LOOP AT lt_data ASSIGNING <fs_main>.
      SELECT SINGLE kbetr fwste hwste FROM bset
        INTO (<fs_main>-kbetr, <fs_main>-fwste, <fs_main>-hwste)
        WHERE belnr = <fs_main>-belnr.

      SELECT SINGLE koart FROM bseg
        INTO (<fs_main>-koart)
        WHERE buzei = 1
        AND belnr = <fs_main>-belnr.


    IF <fs_main>-koart = 'D'.    
          FORMAT COLOR COL_NORMAL INTENSIFIED OFF.
          WRITE:/
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (16) <fs_main>-belnr NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (16) <fs_main>-spart NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (10) <fs_main>-bldat NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP.
                  perc = <fs_main>-kbetr / 10.
                  WRITE: (10) perc NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (5) <fs_main>-waers NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (16) <fs_main>-wrbtr NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (16) <fs_main>-fwste NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (5) <fs_main>-hwaer NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (16) <fs_main>-dmbtr NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP,
                  (16) <fs_main>-hwste NO-GAP,
                  sy-vline NO-GAP.
                  WRITE:/ sy-uline(137).
                  write: <fs_main>-koart. 
    ELSE.   
                  write: 'Não há dados a mostrar.'. 
    ENDIF.   
  ENDLOOP.

ENDFORM.                    "select_data1
```

The result is this one:

[image: runtime result]

The 'D' at the right of the output table shouldn't be `D` for the 3 lines. Only the first one should be `D` and the other two should be `S`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `WRITE <fs_main>-koart.` is inside the block `IF <fs_main>-koart = 'D'.`.

So you always get the `D`. I think that's a problem of the code copy.

You use

```
      SELECT SINGLE koart FROM bseg
        INTO (<fs_main>-koart)
        WHERE buzei = 1
        AND belnr = <fs_main>-belnr.
```

and you don't check `SY-SUBRC`. If no entry is found, the old value of `<fs_main>-koart` keeps in the variable.

I would recommend:

```
      clear <fs_main>-koart.
      "<fs_main>-koart = '?'.    "Alternative
      SELECT SINGLE koart FROM bseg
        INTO (<fs_main>-koart)
        WHERE buzei = 1
        AND belnr = <fs_main>-belnr.
```

or

```
      SELECT SINGLE koart FROM bseg
        INTO (<fs_main>-koart)
        WHERE buzei = 1
        AND belnr = <fs_main>-belnr.
      IF SY-SUBRC NE 0.
        clear <fs_main>-koart.
        "<fs_main>-koart = '?'.    "Alternative
        " or you may skip the output with NEXT
      ENDIF.
```

Comment: It worked... I still have to put clears in the select single above this one too but it work perfecly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have line item (BUZEI) hard coded in your select.  I suspect that is the cause of the repeated data.

Comment: I putet that line there because it was already repeating the data. Even if I take that line off it will repeat the data. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment, I find it really weird you are not filtering by company and year.
remember the same BELNR for a document this year won't be the same document next year. The same with companies.

Please be sure that is what you want your program to show. Because it may become a problem when the fiscal year change or new companies are added to the system.